# Shiny Jerbolta started to disobey

Tags: pokemon-uranium

My Shiny Jerbolta started to disobey.

It was a gift when I first started playing the game. Apparently, those gifts appear from time to time and you can pick them at the market.

The thing is, when my shiny Jerbolta reached level 36, it started to disobey frequently.

Is there a way to make him "friendly" again and follow my commands all the time?

EDIT: I noticed the disobedience at level 36 but I don't know exactly at what level he started to react that way.

Comment: Previous Pokémon games tied disobedience to the gym badges you had (or hadn't) earned. I don't know if Uranium is the same, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was.

Comment: @JonK , I'm about to get my 3rd badge... if the disobedience rate drops, that would be the reason! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You may need the fourth badge to stop the disobedience, previously the level cutoffs for disobedience were 30/50/70/100 on the 2nd/4th/6th/8th badges. Again though, I'm not familiar with Uranium's mechanics in this regard.

Comment: As soon I got my new badge, the rate dropped and with my 4th badge, there is no more disobedience.
@JonK, don't you want to put your comments as answer so I can set it as correct?

Comment: I've been digging around for the actual numbers and have finally found a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemonuranium/comments/4xf4sh/badges_effects/) that had the numbers in. They're not quite what I thought, but fairly close

Comment: I noted that because Jerbolta was 100% obedient from 36 to 38 when I got the 3rd badge.

Comment: It's interesting that it started to happen at level 36 though. It does make me wonder if the values I found are actually correct. Perhaps the second badge goes up to level 35 instead of 30. I'll do a bit more digging and see if I can find something.

Comment: Well... I should have made myself more clear... I noticed that because he was 36 at that time... he was actually holding the Share Exp item so he was gaining level after level but I was not using him. When I used him at some random fight, I saw the "disobey message"... I didn't know about player level when I first wrote the question. I will fix the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Pokémon is disobeying you, you should be able to regain their obedience by acquiring the appropriate level Gym badge. The limits are:

- 1st Badge - Pokémon up to level 20 will obey you
- 2nd Badge - Pokémon up to level 30 will obey you
- 3rd Badge - Pokémon up to level 40 will obey you
- 4th Badge - Pokémon up to level 50 will obey you
- 5th Badge - Pokémon up to level 60 will obey you
- 6th Badge - Pokémon up to level 70 will obey you
- 7th Badge - Pokémon up to level 80 will obey you
- 8th Badge - All* Pokémon will obey you

Due credit to [redditor **Bjcftbl74**](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemonuranium/comments/4xf4sh/badges_effects/d6exnh4) for the majority of this list.

**Nuclear* Pokémon will **always** have a chance to disobey you, even with all of the badges.